# How can I can a vertical ScrollView with two horizontal ScrollViews?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

I'm working in Xcode 8 with Swift 3. How can I can a vertical ScrollView with two horizontal ScrollViews? I've been trying with storyboards and am having a hard time. I am open to a Storyboard or programmatic answer.

EDIT: I was adding a Scroll View in storyboard mode and then adding another View on top of that to be the content view. I then made the View (content view) height tall, such as 1200 and put a label at the top and at the bottom so I would know if it was scrolling. The Scroll View height was set at 579. I ran it and it would not scroll.

Comment: "am having a hard time" is not really a question. What's the problem? This sounds easy enough to do; what happens when you try it?

Comment: Found a good guide here and it is working for me. http://www.appcoda.com/uiscrollview-introduction/

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

class ScrollExVC: UIViewController {

    var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "tiger.jpg"))

        scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: view.bounds)
        scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        scrollView.contentSize = imageView.bounds.size
        scrollView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

        scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
        view.addSubview(scrollView)


    }

}
```